# Variables don't read properly from JS test scripts to Solidity Contract

Tags: javascript, testing, ethereum, solidity, truffle

So I don't know if I phrased the title properly, but I'm having problems with variables in my Javascript Test scripts. When i try to send a variable in my test script to the solidity contract it doesn't receive the same variable in the events emitted.

Here's my JS Test Script

```
const NFCertificate = artifacts.require("../contracts/NFCertificate.sol");

contract("NFCertificate", accounts => {
let account1 = 0x49f0C9b4Ab0b0DedDABf8b62e6089C9b20f936fa;
let certNum = 23477264530040661;

it("It should make first account an owner", async () => {
    let instance = await NFCertificate.deployed();
    let owner = await instance.owner();
    assert.equal(owner, account1);
});

it("It should send a token and save it", async () => {
    let instance = await NFCertificate.deployed();
    await instance.createCertificate("hello", "world", "www", account1, {from: "0x49f0C9b4Ab0b0DedDABf8b62e6089C9b20f936fa"});
    await instance.checkTokenStatus(certNum);
    //await instance.checkOwnerStatus(account1, certNum);
    //await instance.destroyCertificate(certNum, {from: "0x49f0C9b4Ab0b0DedDABf8b62e6089C9b20f936fa"});
    assert.deepEqual(0, 1, "...");
 });
});
```

Note the values given in the "account1" and "certNum" variables. Below is the event from the contract when I run the test script.

```
returnID(ID: 16514060434978983)
returnID(ID: 23477264530040661)
returnID(ID: 123477264530040661)
Transfer(from: <indexed>, to: <indexed>, tokenId: <indexed>)
ReturnNewCertificate(index: 0, CID: 23477264530040661, msgsender: 0x49f0c9b4ab0b0deddabf8b62e6089c9b20f936fa, onwershipHistory: 0x49f0c9b4ab0b0b7d8d98c5f33841ce0d00000000)
ReturnStatus(status: false, CID: 23477264530040660)
```

Notice how the last two events have some discrepancies in the variables.

First, the CID number in the event "ReturnNewCertificate" is generated within the contract based on sha256 algorithm. I hardcoded this same number as the value for the "certNum" variable in the JS script and sent it through the "checkTokenStatus" function that checks to see if this ID exists. However from the "ReturnStatus" event we can see the ID that was sent from the test script has the last digit wrong, from "1" to a "0" (compare CID's in both events).

This same problem can be seen when sending the "account1" variable through the "createCertificate" function, check the "ownershipHistory" variable within the "ReturnNewCertificate" event and compare that to the account1 variable in the test script.

Below are the solidity functions I am running within the test script.

```
function createCertificate(string title, string data, string url, address owner) public returns (uint certificateID, uint licenseID, uint assetID) {
    assetID = generateAssetID(data);
    AssetIDS.push(assetID);
    certificateID = generateCertificateID(assetID, owner);
    Certificate memory certificate = Certificate(Certificates.length, certificateID, assetID, 0, url, title, owner, owner, new address[](0), true);
    uint index = Certificates.push(certificate)-1;
    CIDtoIndex[certificateID] = index;
    Certificates[index].ownershipHistory.push(owner);
    //License
    licenseID = createLicense(certificate.index, certificateID, owner, owner);
    //ERC721 Mint
    NFCProtocols.mint(owner, certificateID);
    emit ReturnNewCertificate(certificate.index, certificate.certificateID, msg.sender, Certificates[certificate.index].ownershipHistory);
}

function checkTokenStatus(uint certificateID) public {
    bool status = NFCProtocols.exists(certificateID);
    emit ReturnStatus(status, certificateID);
}
```

Finally I'm sorry If this is all a little confusing, I'm a little new to coding in general so my code might not be the prettiest. Also Ive been scratching my head trying to figure out the problem for a few hours now, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, when declaring variables in Javascript declare them like such:

```
let account1 = web3.eth.accounts[0];
let certNum = web3.toBigNumber('23282430602617218');
```